# Android MMS Intent with with Image and body text

Tags: android, android-intent, message, mms

I am trying to create an intent that will start the MMS application for me with an image file attached and some pre-defined  text present in the message body.

Thus far I've been able to accomplish either or, but not both at the same time.

Things I've tried (with their results):

```
sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND,Uri.parse("mms://"));
sendIntent.setType("image/gif");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgStreamUri);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "HelloWorld");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Send"));    
/**********
Image file is attached but no text added to message body.
 **********/

sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/gif");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgStreamUri);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "HelloWorld");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "WorldHello");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,"Send"));
/**********
Image file is attached but no text added to message body(or subject or anything).
 **********/
```

Does anyone know how I can attach both body text and an image file to an mms intent that will launch the default messaging application with the appropriate items filled in?

**EDIT:** Tested the code @lenik provided in answer. It is working on some devices, here's what I found

Works correctly:

- Epic 4g (Galaxy S)
- Epic 4g Touch (Galaxy S II)
- Galaxy Nexus(ICS 4.0.4)
- HTC Desire (Froyo 2.2)
- Motorola Photon

Image attached but no text:

- Sidekick 4g
- Samsung Transform Ultra

Anyone know if I am basically s.o.l. on the devices that don't work properly this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi how are you");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.gif")));
intent.setType("image/gif"); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Send"));
```

Comment: I get no text added. What device did you run on?

Comment: works on my HTC Desire (Froyo 2.2) and Galaxy Nexus (ICS 4.0.4).

Comment: please, try to use my sorce **verbatim**, most probably the problem is related to your `imgStreamUri` parameter, if it has wrong contents, the text or file don't show properly in MMS message.

Comment: I've just been able to test on a wider range of devices. See my edit for results.

Comment: @lenik how to attached audio file in mms programmatically.

Comment: @Harshid I think same way, just supply the proper file name and change MIME type (`intent.setType()`) accordingly

Comment: @lenik i am attach image from mipmap instead of SD card the message is showing "You can't add this picture in message"

 shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.mipmap.ic_launcher));