# How to compose SMS via intents without recipient

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I'd like to open the default SMS application and load the content with some text, but I don't want to provide a phone number. Instead, I'd like to leave that field in blank so that the user can choose the recipient.

This is how the SMS app is usually invoked:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, "smsto:666");
```

However, I'd like to do as when opening email client:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Is it possible to do the same? If so, which attributes should I set to the intent so that it opens the SMS app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without appending phone number to URI also works:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello World!");  
    startActivity(intent);
```

I guess it works also with ACTION_VIEW action as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372665/813951

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "hello world");  
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"); 
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Is that intent type standard?

Comment: is there any way to attach photo to this sms?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490329/android-mms-intent-with-with-image-and-body-text