# send a jpg image throug MMS using HTC

Tags: android, mms, htcsense

I am trying to send a jpg image through MMS using an HTC device (2.3.5, HTC Desire HD-Sense), I am using the following snippet

```
File sendfilepath = new File("file://" + sendfile);
Uri urimms = Uri.fromFile(sendfilepath);

Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, urimms);
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It opens the Messaging app but it does not attach the image. I do not know why? It shows a toast "Cannot load message"

Comment: Does logcat show any reason for why it is failing?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mmsto:<number>");
intent.putExtra("address", <number>);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, urimms);
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(intent);
```

Otherwise these links look to be a little outdated but you should be able to translate everything pretty well:

- [Android MMS Intent with with Image and body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490329/android-mms-intent-with-with-image-and-body-text)
- http://androidforums.com/application-development/25988-send-image-action_send.html

Comment: What you have written does not work with HTC sense. It works with other Android devices.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  The author of this post says it works on 2.2:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490329/android-mms-intent-with-with-image-and-body-text

Comment: IT is 2.3.5 , HTC Desire HD(Sense)

Comment: Okay, I would try the above link then.  There shouldn't have been too big of changes between 2.2 and 2.3.5 in regards to this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
        sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/image_4.png"));
        sendIntent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(sendIntent);;
```