# Unable to attach audio file to Samsung Devices

Tags: android, android-intent

I unable to attach Audio file to Some of the Samsung Devices like Samsung GalaxyS2,Nexus etc.I don't know whats the problem.I am able to attach all other devices.Please someone help me for my this issue.My code is as:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body",
                    getResources().getText(R.string.Message));
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms",
                    "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");


            AssetManager mngr = getAssets();
            InputStream path = null;
            try {
                path = mngr.open("*.mp3");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(path, 1024);

            // get the bytes one by one
            int current = 0;
            //
            try {
                while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {

                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // /TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] bitmapdata = baf.toByteArray();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath(), "*.mp3");

            // if (file.exists() == true) {
            // } else {
            // Log.v("directory is created", "new  dir");
            // file.mkdir();
            // }

            FileOutputStream fos;

            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(bitmapdata);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // handle exception
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle exception
            }

            final File file1 = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    "*.mp3");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);

            Log.e("Path", "" + uri);

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
            // sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mms_uri.toString());

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
            // startActivity(sendIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: not getting any error in Log cat and also got the correct path of SD card where i stored my Audio file.The only thing is that i am not able to attach audio file to Some of the Samsung devices like Galaxy S2,Nexus etc.And I am Successfully attaching Audio file to All other Devices.I dont know where i am wrong in above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the class name explicitly by calling `setClassName()`. Instead just set the action, type and extra as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491109/165674).

Comment: not getting any error in Log cat and also got the correct path of SD card where i stored my Audio file.The only thing is that i am not able to attach audio file to Some of the Samsung devices like Galaxy S2,Nexus etc.And I am Successfully attaching Audio file to All other Devices.I dont know where i am wrong in above code?

Comment: What setType i have to Use for attaching Audio file to MMS?

Comment: @Romil Use `"audio/*"` for audio files.

Comment: Actually i did it before but still got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that there is ExternalStorage i.e. sd card available on the device. Your S2 or Nexus probably does not have the sd card. I have seen this issue before.

Comment: To overcome this problem what should i have to do?